# CSS Grid Centering

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a problem vertically aligning center/middle in a grid cell.

I have the following code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width:100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.itemBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
   <div class="grid-container tab active" id="pageHome">
      <div class="itemBox content">1</div>
      <div class="itemBox"><span class="test">2</span></div>
      <span class="itemBox">3</span>
      <div class="itemBox s4x1">4</div>
      <div class="itemBox s1x2">5</div>
      <div class="itemBox">6</div>
      <div class="itemBox">7</div>
      <div class="itemBox">8</div>  
      <div class="itemBox s1x2">9</div>
      <div class="itemBox">10</div>
      <div class="itemBox">11</div>  
      <div class="itemBox">12</div>  
    </div>
```

this produces
[image]

But i cannot get the numbers to be centered in the boxes without the border collapsing to the middle as well like this:

[image]

if i add

```
align-items: center;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please show your html as well. preferably as a [MCVE]

Comment: Ive updated the question with the needed html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` to achieve this

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width:100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}
.s2 {
grid-row: span 2;
}
.itemBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  place-items: center stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container tab active" id="pageHome">
      <div class="itemBox content">1</div>
      <div class="itemBox"><span class="test">2</span></div>
      <span class="itemBox">3</span>
      <div class="itemBox s1">4</div>
      <div class="itemBox s2">5</div>
      <div class="itemBox">6</div>
      <div class="itemBox">7</div>
      <div class="itemBox">8</div>  
      <div class="itemBox s1x2">9</div>
      <div class="itemBox">10</div>
      <div class="itemBox">11</div>  
      <div class="itemBox">12</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - Just what i needed..

Answer (score 0):

use some line height for your `.itemBox` class

```
 .itemBox {
            border: 1px solid white;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height:100px;
        }
```

2. 

Answer (score 0):

```
.itemBox {
 border: 1px solid white;
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

To vertically align text inside div you have to make the "line-height" property is equal to the height of the div container.